# change the backcolor in a datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I tried to change the backcolor in a specific column when the cell value changed.
I didn't find the method to do that and I don't know how to do that.

ok ----> backcolor in green.
nok ----> backcolor in red.

thank you very much for your help.

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        String StartCourse = dr[0].ToString();
        string EndCourse = dr[1].ToString();
        DateTime SystemTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        DateTime StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(StartCourse);
        DateTime EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(EndCourse);

        if (StartTime.TimeOfDay.Ticks <= SystemTime.TimeOfDay.Ticks && SystemTime.TimeOfDay.Ticks < EndTime.TimeOfDay.Ticks)
            {
                 ds.Tables[0].Rows[count][5] = "ok";      
            }

        else
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[count][5] = "nok";
            }

        count++;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call this Procedure:

**UPDATED**

```
void ColorGrid()
{
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) 
     {
        if (row.Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "ok") 
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green; 
        }
        else
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I have an error for GridViewRow : type or namespace " gridviewrow" could not be found ( are you missing a using directive. thank you for helping me.

Comment: @user1112847: oh sorry, it's not `GridViewRow` but `DataGridViewRow`.

Comment: error in row.BackColor ---> does not contain a definition for BackColor.

Comment: error in row.cells[5].Text == "ok" ----> possible unintended reference comparaison to get a value comparaison, cast the left hand side to type string

Comment: thank you for helping me : row.Cells[5].Text --> system.windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell does not contain a definition for 'Text'.

Comment: @user1112847 change it to `row.Cells[5].Value.ToString()`

Comment: I tried and the warining is  Possible unintended reference comparaison; to get a value comparaison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'.

Answer (score 1):

See the [DataGridViewColumn.DefaultCellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.defaultcellstyle%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) property. This allows you to set a `DataGridViewCellStyle` for a column. This class has a [BackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.backcolor%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) property.

See the following MSDN article for more detail:

[Cell Styles in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx)

Comment: yes I tried and nothing displayed into the datagridview.    ds.Tables[0].Rows[count][5] = "ok";
                         dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.green;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.DataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[5].Text == "ok")
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this on my own project.

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
 {

     row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = (row.Cells[5].Text == "ok")? Color.Green:Color.Red;
 }
```

If that still didn't work, try delete that datagridview and add it again. 
Be sure to name it again as dataGridView1 and attached its corresponding events.